# How to apply styles to user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:SpoilerControl x:Name="spoiler" Other="true">
        <UserControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="UserControl">
                <Setter Property="Secret" Value="New secret value"/>
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Style>
    </local:SpoilerControl>
 </StackPanel>
```

I have a user control which was property `Secret` which is just string value. How can I set that in styles? I think I need to set something else in TargetType? Because it doesn't build (can't find the property).

> error MC4005: Cannot find the Style Property 'Secret' on the type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl'

Comment: How is `Secret` declared? Is it dependency property?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined `Secret` as a dependency property, `TargetType="{x:Type local:SpoilerControl}"` should work